# How to bring down the output voltage of a 2 x 25 VAC 6 A transformer? (Around 35 VDC after rectifiers)

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

As above

2 x 25 VAC, 6 A is an off-the-shelf 300 VA transformer.

The ideal transformer secondary is 2 x 22 VAC, 6.8 A but it's not available without going custom and that's beyond my budget.

Things I've thought about:

- voltage divider but with 6 A secondary (and I need the maximum current I can get from the transformer); I'm not sure if this is feasible.
- a voltage regulator might be more feasible than the voltage divider, and the power I need to sink (via a heatsink) might be OK especially if I use a low-dropout part.

Thoughts?

Comment: Whether you use an LDO or a conventional linear regulator, the power loss in the regulator will be the same if the input and output conditions are the same. And a voltage divider should *never* be used for power. At this power level you need a proper switching converter.

Comment: Is your end goal 35 V DC or 22 V AC?

Comment: You should consider that the primary voltage can vary by about 10%, so you will need to design voltage regulation accordingly. Off-the-shelf transformers are usually 24 VAC nominal, but open circuit are probably about 25 VAC. And the voltage of a capacitor filter will vary greatly depending on value and load.

Answer (score 5):

As you have ruled out the correct method of doing this, here are a few kludges to consider (random order rather than ordered by attractiveness)

- Add a few more diodes in series in the output rectifier, that will lose you a few stiff volts, but at several amps burn quite a lot of heat.
- If it's a toroidal transformer, the low voltage secondaries are invariably the outside windings. Could you unwind a few turns from the secondary? Twice if you want to use the secondary centre-tap, though the second secondary may be buried under the first. This reduces transformer resistance, so improves dissipation and regulation. I built a custom 600 VA transformer by unwinding and replacing the secondaries from a toroidal.
- If you want to leave the transformer intact, and it's a toroidal with an accessible hole, then wind a few turns to put in anti-series with the secondary. This increases the secondary resistance, so reduces the transformer regulation. Two needed if you want the secondary centre-tap.
- Or put several dozen turns through the hole, and put them in series with the primary. This will reduce the core flux, so reduce core losses, magnetostriction noise, current inrush when turned on, all good things. It also increases winding resistance, so reduces regulation. Only one needed.
- Buy a low power 10:1 30 VA step-down transformer, and use it as an autotransformer to supply the main transformer 90% of the supply voltage. Same effects to core flux and regulation as above.

Comment: Depending on the transformer, winding more turns might be difficult. Toroidal mains transformers are usually wound with a winding factor very close to 1, only leaving enough room for a central mounting screw.

Comment: @Hearth YMMV. The ones I've met in my multi-decade career all had room for another 10% of windings, or were filled with a resin plug holding a mounting nut. The automatic winding machines need quite a bit a clearance to get the shuttle through, much more than a hobbyist poking a wire or ten through.

Comment: @Neil_UK how do I "reseal" the transformer after unwinding a few turns from the secondary? (would this also lower the current output? I guess the answer is no but just checking)

Comment: @mrjayviper What you you mean by 'reseal'? There's no compressed gas to come out. Were you intending to operate under water? Removing a few turns from the secondary reduces the voltage, which is what you want. It also reduces the transformer dissipation at any given output current, so it increases the permissible output current for any given temperature rise. Reducing the output voltage reduces the short circuit current slightly, but you're not intending to operate it into a short circuit for more time than it takes the fuse to blow.

Comment: @Neil_UK the toroidal I've used seems to be "wrap" in "plastic"

Comment: @mrjayviper so wrap it up again

Comment: @Neil_UK with what?

Comment: @mrjayviper with the plastic tape you took off carefully, or new plastic tape. My choice would be nothing, as the secondaries are at a touch safe voltage, and any covering increases the thermal resistance to ambient, and so the running temperature of the transformer.